# JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused?

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-ase

When I use following code to connect sybase ASE 16,I get an error:

> JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused

The code is :

```
package sybase;

import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.*;
public class Conn2ASE {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
        String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.100.120:5000/master";
        Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
        sysProps.put("user", "sa");
        sysProps.put("password", "560128");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, sysProps);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "select id,name,crdate from dbo.sysobjects where type='U'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("oject_id:"+rs.getString(1)+",oject_name:"+rs.getString(2)); 
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

What's the problem? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: It means that there is no sybase server running on 192.168.100.120 port 5000, or the connection is blocked by the firewall.

Comment: I have stopped the firewall by `sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service`, and the ASE is also running on 192.168.100.120 port 5000, is there any other reasons?

Comment: Such type of error usually comes when theres any issue with jdbc connection url i.e. String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.100.120:5000/master";

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Any resolution ?